React Native - Linking.openUrl() - Android 14
I'm getting this error [Error: Could not open URL 'micoope://app/cuenta/token': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=micoope://app/... }] trying to open a deeplink from my react native app. I know it is product of the new Security Policy described here
However I'm not sure if I should implement the modification of the creation of the explicit intent within my project (i don't even know in which file should i do it), or that should be done by the React Native development team. I'll appreciate any kind of help.
Here is my AndroidManifest file:
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="micoope" android:host="app" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


Set android:exported to true?

When android:exported is set to true it works well but the idea is to keep the value as false for the sake of security

Then you explicitly specify the package in the intent. The link you posted has stated the solution.

I added this block of code inside my MainActivity.kt but still doesn't work
    super.onStart()
    val uri = Uri.parse("micoope://app")
    val explicitIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri)
    explicitIntent.setPackage(this.packageName)
    this.startActivity(explicitIntent)
  }```
